# Did the fake shogun agree to be killed by Hattori Zenzou?

Tags: gintama

In an episode of the 2015 series IIRC, Hattori Zenzou kills a fake double shogun to save shogun Tokugawa Shige Shige. Did this double agree to give his life to save the real shogun or did Hattori Zenzou killed him without his permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double was Kagemaru, and he was fully prepared to die for Shige Shige's sake. In episode 302, he says:

> "I, Kagemaru, wouldn't be here if he(Shige Shige) hadn't saved my life
>   back then. Use it for his sake".

So yeah Hattori and Kagemaru were both in on the plan.